# Duas variaveis e um group by? PHP e MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, chat

Estou fazendo um sistema de chat privado (apenas entre duas pessoas) bem simples com PHP e MySQL, Jquery e HTML/CSS.
No banco de dados, a tabela tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
id (int)
remetente (varchar)
destinatario (varchar)
texto (text)
horario (datetime)
```

a id é auto incremento, o remetente e o destinatário são usernames salvos em outra tabela com informações dos usuarios, o texto é o texto enviado e o horário é o horário e a data que a mensagem foi enviada.

Na caixa de entrada, a minha ideia era dar um mysql_query e selecionar todas as mensagens dessa tabela onde o destinatario fosse igual ao usuario logado, agrupar pelo remetente e ordenar pela data e hora desc. Fica assim:

```
$mensagensqr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mensagens WHERE destinatario = '$usuario' GROUP BY remetente ORDER BY horario desc");
```

Sendo $usuario, o username do usuario logado.

Pra mostrar na tela, por exemplo, eu faço um:

```
while($mensagensfa = mysql_fetch_assoc($mensagensqr)){echo "certo usuario mandou tantas mensagens";}
```

Até aí, tá dando tudo certo, porém eu quero mostrar as mensagens enviadas pelo usuario logado também. Vejam bem, se for olhar na primeira query que eu citei, só mostra mensagens onde o destinatario = '$usuario'. Porém, se eu colocar "OR remetente = '$usuario'" na query pra mostrar as mensagens enviadas pelo usuario, ele vai continuar agrupando pelo remetente.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como eu resolvo isso?

PS: sobre o `mysql` sei que está obsoleto, o problema é a *query*.

Comment: Seria bom dar um exemplo do que você quer na saída. Pra que está usando o GROUP, antes de mais nada? Só vai mostrar a última? E no caso do `OR` fica mais fácil escrever `WHERE $usuario IN ( remetente, destinatario)` se quiser achar mensagens dos dois. Quanto ao problema em usar o OR, como saiu, e como era pra ter saido o resultado?

Comment: Não sei se entendi todas as perguntas. Esse código não é do chat em si, imagine aquela página do facebook ou a página inicial do whatsapp, onde todas as mensagens ficam. Lá agrupa por pessoa e só mostra a ultima mensagem, o horário, etc, com um link que abre o resto das mensagens. Por isso, usei o GROUP. Quanto ao problema, como eu estou agrupando pelo remetente, quando o usuário logado é o remetente, ao invés de aparecer o nome do destinatário, aparece o nome do remetente (por que está agrupando pelo remetente). Eu sei, tá confuso, vou adicionar mais detalhes a pergunta. Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Ai o problema não é o agrupamento, no PHP você precisa por um `echo $remetente = $usuario ? $destinatario : $ remetente;` - besteira querer mexer com isso no SQL (e de qualquer forma, a lógica é a mesma. O remetente, não importa como você faça, vai ser quem mandou. Para mostrar ou um ou outro, precisa dessa lógica que eu comentei. Se for no SQL, é SELECT IF( remetente = $usuario_php, destinatario, remetente ) AS nome

Comment: Acho que entendi e resolvi em partes. Agora está aparecendo os grupos das mensagens duplicados. Acredito que seja porque o mesmo usuário está no remetente em uma linha e no destinatário em outra linha, no banco de dados, e aí quando o while roda, ele acaba mostrando duas vezes o mesmo usuário. Tenho que arrumar um jeito de se o usuário já ter sido mostrado, não mostrar de novo. De qualquer forma, preciso muito dormir agora. Muito obrigado mesmo, já foi um avanço! Se tiver algum jeito de eu te agradecer, dar um like, favorito, ou sei lá, mostrar que você me ajudou, diz aí, por favor.

Comment: Descanse lá, depois se der a gente dá uma melhorada na pergunta ou revisa ela pro seu problema atual (como não tem resposta, você pode por o seu código atual nela mais tarde) e aí eu ou outro usuário pode postar uma resposta "oficial" depois.

Comment: Não entendi o que você falou com "agrupar pelo remetente e ordenar pela hora". Como você está fazendo uma consulta com o coringa "*", não esperaria ver um `group by` nela. Também esperaria ver um agregador em alguma coluna selecionada ao fazer o `group by`, mas não vejo nenhuma. Minhas ideias em que a sua frase fizesse sentido implica a existência de mais do que duas pessoas no chat como um todo (mesmo que toda comunicação seja feita em canais _unicast_)

Answer (score 1):

Olá, uma forma de resolver é usando o UNION do MySQL, onde você consegue executar duas consultas, com se estivesse trazendo os dados de duas tabelas.

Tenta desta forma:

```
$mensagensqr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mensagens
WHERE destinatario = '$usuario'
GROUP BY remetente ORDER BY horario DESC
UNION
SELECT * FROM mensagens
WHERE remetente = '$usuario'
GROUP BY remetente ORDER BY horario desc");
```

Comment: Uma observação: Apesar do MySQL não reclamar, o GROUP BY deve vir acompanhado dos campos explicitamente no SELECT, ex.: SELECT remetente FROM mensagens ... GROUP BY remetente, senão voce pode ter resultados inesperados no seu select e perder um bom tempo quebrando a cabeça pra resolver.